# Dynamically create a simple report template

Tags: excel

I have an Excel report I am building over a data sheet with many rows. I want to be able dynamically to create the report without having manually change the customized layout because people in the office know very little about IT and can ending up messing up the formulas when adding rows etc. Let's say my data sheet looks like this:

```
_____________________________________________________
Dept. Code | Contract Name | Revenue | Costs | Manager 
A1           First           20        15      John
A2           Second          50        25      Paul
A5           Third           100       35      John
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to build something like this:

```
_____________________________________________________
Manager: John
Dept. Code | Contract Name | Revenue | Costs
A1           First           20        15
A5           Third           100       35

Manager: Paul
Dept. Code | Contract Name | Revenue | Costs
A2           Second          50        25
----------------------------------------------------
```

Therefore, if the data sheet has another contract added, then it will automatically be added to the respective Manager. The same way if I add another Manager onto the datasheet, then the new Manager and its contracts are listed.

If I learn how to do this simple process then I can customise their report exactly the way I intend to.

Comment: Do you intend to do all of this in Excel (as opposed to using a dedicated reporting tool, such as Crystal Reports, SSRS, etc)? If so, I suggest looking into using VBA.

Comment: Never heard of Crystal Reports etc. Plus, they already have most of things already set up in excel. It just a matter of doing this small processing. If it is possible doing it using VBA, any idea how this can be achieved? I know programming in Java and C++ but I don't know VBA. thanks anyway

Comment: Or what better known as macros. here are some tutorials- [simple macro](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Simple-Macro-in-Microsoft-Excel) and [macro tutorial](http://spreadsheets.about.com/b/2007/02/15/excel-macro-tutorial.htm)

Comment: I used a macro to do a the windows logged user which was pretty simple. I need more help than just saying: do in VBA :x

Answer (score 0):

You might find a PivotTable adequate, though the `Manager` names would not be positioned quite where you show them in your suggested output layout. In the image the PT is in the same sheet (A8:E11) but in a separate sheet (the default) may be more practical:

[image: SO25118643 example]

When selecting the source data I suggest entire columns, though that will probably mean an entry in the PT for Manager `(blank)`. The PT will need to be refreshed if to incorporate additions/revisions to the raw data.